# For-each in ionic2 with angularjs2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I make one application with IONIC-2 Beta version. I want to use *for-each* loop. is it possible to use for each in angular-V2?

Thanks.

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#lists

Comment: Where do you want to do the foreach, in the HTML or in the TypeScript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First in the `Component`, you have to declare the array you want to show:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class HomePage {

  displayData : [];

  constructor() {
    this.displayData = [
      {
        "text": "item 1",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "text": "item 2",
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "text": "item 3",
        "value": 3
      },
      {
        "text": "item 4",
        "value": 4
      },
      {
        "text": "item 5",
        "value": 5
      },
    ];
  }
}
```

If you want to change the values in the code, you can do it by doing:

```
// We iterate the array in the code
for(let data of this.displayData) {
  data.value = data.value + 5;
}
```

And then in your View you can print them like this:

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
  <ion-list *ngFor="let data of displayData; let i = index" no-lines>
    <ion-item>Index: {{ i }} - Text: {{ data.text }} - Value: {{ data.value }}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Please notice that part `*ngFor="let data of displayData"` where:

- `displayData` is the array we defined in the `Component`
- `let data of ...` defines a new variable called `data`, which represents each of the elements of the `displayData` array.
- we can access the properties for each array element by using that `data` variable, and interpolation like `{{ data.propertyName }}`.

Comment: @sebaferreras How can i get index?

Comment: @RaghavRangani I've edited the answer to include the index in the `ngFor`

Comment: @sebaferreras Thank you.

Comment: how can i get the index of the data in for loop?

Comment: @EbruGüngör The index is being stored in the `i` template variable, so  you can use it by using that variable: `... <ion-item>Index: {{ i }} - Text: {{ 
data.text }} - Value: {{ data.value }}</ion-item> ...`