# Angular2,Ionic2:How to access an array of objects inside another array of objects in typescript?

Tags: angular, object, typescript, ionic2, arrayofarrays

I'm completely new to the concept of using arrays in angular2. I've my JSON data coming from the backend which I'm storing in an array called "arr". But I want to access an array which is present in every object that is in "arr" i.e every object in "arr" has an array which has some elements in it. I want to access that array in my .ts file not HTML file. I need to do some modifications on that in .ts file so I want to know how do I create a pipe for the same.

I read that we need to use pipes.But I'm not understanding how do I use a pipe for this.
If you can see in the picture there is a main array which has 3 objects and each of the 3 objects have an array called categories which again has objects. I want to access the field "category" inside categories for all the 3 objects present in the main array. Can someone help me do it ?

[image: This is how my data looks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for pipes here, pipes would be used for actually displaying data in template, e.g if you would need to iterate object keys, which can not be used with `*ngFor`. But since you want to manipulate data in the component....

You need two `forEaches` to reach every each category inside the different objects. And you need to do this from the callback (subscribe) after you have received the data, here's some more info on that: [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

I suggest you do the http requests in a service, and subscribe to the data in your component, so in your component, call that service method and subscribe to the response and then use forEach:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getData()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.searchResults = data;
      // call method or manipulate data here since response has been received
      this.manipulateData();
    });
}

manipulateData() {
    this.searchResults.forEach((x:any)=> { // iterate outer array
      x.categories.forEach((y:any) => { // iterate the categories of each object
        console.log(y.name) // ... or whatever properties you have
        // manipulate your data
      })
    })
}
```

### [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/HdwR6WCFs961zntcYKXE?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a ton. It's working. You made my day. I have a doubt, I did write my service call in a service.ts file and used it in my component.So what I did is I called the function "manipulateData()" inside subscribe and then in this manipulateData() I wrote 2 foreachs.But it didn't work.So I directly wrote the forEachs inside the subscribe and it works. Any reason for this? Also to add to my question a further. Can you tell me how can I fetch only unique category ids instead of all the category ids?

Comment: Hard to say why it doesn't work with the `manipulateData`-method based on not seeing any of your code. It *should* work, like I provided in plunker. As to your second question, you'd have to write some logic to filter the only unique id's from your data.... Here would be a question pretty close to yours I think :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: this.Service.getData.subscribe(resp=>{
     this.searchResults = resp.data;
 
   this.searchResults.forEach((x:any)=> {
      x.categories.forEach((y:any) => {object
        this.category=y.categoryid;
      console.log(this.category); 
      })
    }); this worked. but this one didn't work     this.testService.post('search/getSearchResults',this.searchobj).subscribe(resp=>{
     this.searchResults = resp.data; this.manipulatedata();
      })
    });

Comment: Your second snippet of code is just wrong, so trash that. Your first one looks good, but instead of doing the foreach in the subscription, you could call a method and do the for each there instead, like my answer suggests. But it's not necessary. It's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

If it's in html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of arr">
 {{item.aliasname}}
 <div *ngFor="let category of item.categories">
    {{category.name}}
 </div>
</div>
```

In type script you can use a foreach loop

```
arr.forEach(element => {
    element.forEach(category => {
       console.log(category.name);
       // Do whatever you want
       // You can access any field like that : category.yourField
    });
});
```

[An other way to foreach in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524761/for-each-in-ionic2-with-angularjs2)

Comment: Thanks. But I'm sorry I want to do this in typescript.

Comment: @Impromptu_Coder I've added it ;)

Comment: @Impromptu_Coder it's in my answer, the second part

Comment: @Impromptu_Coder Can't go further if you don't provide any line of code. I showed you how to loop througt nested array in Angular2. Can't do better without any code.

Comment: this.http.get('results/exams',{ }).subscribe(resp=>{
     this.searchResults = resp.data;
   console.log(this.searchResults);
    },
    err=>{console.log(err);},
    ()=>{});

      this.searchResults.forEach(element => {
    element.forEach(category => {
       console.log(category.name);
    });
});
 }  This is what I've tried and it shows the error that I mentioned above. My API call is working.